# Jquery Sortable divs change position dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want to ask how to change position of sortable divs on runtime... 
here is my html code..

```
<div id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <div id="div1" class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</div>
    <div id="div2"  class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</div>
</div>
```

here is my jquery code..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#div2").css({
                left: 701.33334350585937,
                top: 6.3333358764648437
            });

            $("#div1").css({
                left: 701.33334350585937,
                top: 50.3333358764648437
            });

            $("#div1").collapsible = true;

            $("#sortable2").css({
                height: 'auto'
            });
        });
```

when i set the position of div and set property position 'absolute' so its change position of divs but problem is 'sortable' div hieght not grow. and second thing is you cannot the change the position of divs through drag drop please help me how to resolve it..
because of absolute..

thanks in advance..

Comment: can you please create JSfiddle and explain ?

Comment: why you need to modify the position of that div's ?

Comment: if anyone change the position of div it can be change...

Comment: What is your reasoning for setting `position:absolute;` on the sortable elements? Can you not achieve your styling needs by manipulating the container div?

Comment: $("#div2").css({
                position:'absolute',
                left: 701.33334350585937,
                top: 6.3333358764648437
            });

            $("#div1").css({
position:'absolute',                
left: 701.33334350585937,
                top: 50.3333358764648437
            });

if i am not set absolute property so div position not change in runtime..
if i set the absolute property so i cannot drag and drop divs..

Comment: @Arsalan im not sure what that last comment means, this does not explain why you need to set `position:absolute;` on a sortable div, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: "if i am not set absolute property so div position not change in runtime" So you dont want them to be moveable when the page loads? Maybe Im not getting this part?

Comment: i want both functionality div position will be change on runtime and also i can drop one div to another

Comment: Ok, when you say "div position will be change on runtime" can you explain where the div is to begin with and where you want to move it to?

Comment: one div drop to another div..

Comment: Do you have multiple "drop areas" and you want to programatically move a sortable element from one drop area to another?

Comment: yes i have multiple drop areas. yes i want programmatically

Comment: This will let you style move the elements while maintaining the drag and drop functionality. But I have a feeling this is not really what you need... http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/4ePe6/124/

Comment: If you want to programmatically move elements from one list to another see http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/4ePe6/126/

Comment: can you please set the div position and move...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to simply change the location of the divs.  Since you are using jquery use the following code and that will work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sortable2').sortable()
    }
</script>
```

Make sure you are also using jquery ui in your html page.

For Download go to: http://jqueryui.com/download/

For Documentation on how to use .sortable() go to: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/